# Add DateTimepicker plugin in phonegap build config.xml

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I had installed plugin for Datetimepicker for wp8 phonegap from

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-datetime-picker.git
```

And its working fine in local machine in Emulator,but when i convert it to XAP file its not working,i dont know how to add plugin in config.xml in phonegap build.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = ""
    versionCode=""
    version   = "">
    <name>test</name>
    <description>
    </description>
    <author href="" email="">

    </author>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="default" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="internalOnly" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
    <preference name="ErrorUrl" value=""/>
    <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0x000000"/>
    <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false"/>
    <preference name="LoadingDialog" value=","/> 
    <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <gap:platform name="android" />
    <gap:platform name="winphone" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media"  />
    <icon src="img/applogo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="img/applogo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="img/applogo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="img/applogo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="img/applogo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" />
    <icon src="img/applogo.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" />
    <icon src="img/applogo.png" />
    <gap:splash src="img/applogo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="img/applogo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="img/applogo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="img/applogo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="img/applogo.png" gap:platform="winphone" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />
</widget>
```

Please help me to resolve the Problem

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide us with some details about the error message and, if possible, the things you have tried to build the XAP file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talk with leecrossley,

he said there is no build service for the plugin

Answer (score 0):

The plugin must be added under the  tag of the config.xml file in your Cordova-iOS application's project folder.

```
<plugin name="service_name" value="PluginClassName" />
```

Comment: I am using windows 8 phonegap it locally runs well but i dont know why did not run as XAP please tell me some suggestions there is config.xml please see that

Answer (score 0):

I asked the author about this to use it in my project,

He replied.

```
Apologies, there’s no detailed documentation (yet). Something like this would show the date picker when an element with class “date-input” is clicked (untested):

$(".date-input").bind("click", function() {
    datetimepicker.selectDate(function (date) {
        console.log(date);
    });
});

Once the date is selected, the callback function will log the selected date to the console, but you can do whatever with it.

Lee.
```

The value you get will be in a weird format you had to parse it using date object

```
This code would convert to a JavaScript date object:

date = new Date(parseInt(date, 10));

You can then format the date in any way you want.
```

I have successfully implemented it, if you want any help then ask me! hope this answer satisfies your question!